# VMware vSphere Web Client - Login is disable temporary

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, vsphere, vmware-tools

I have problem when am trying to login in to the **VMware vSphere Web Client** VIA Google chrome

I enter the following

User name
Password

User name and password are correct

but I get the following message

```
Login is disable temporary while your previos session is logging out Please try again or restart your browser
```

I want to say that I restart my PC XP ,

but still have the same problem

Please advice what could be the problem , ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that you have some cookies that are causing vSphere login to fail.
Try logging in incognito tab (ctrl+shift+N).
If that doesn't help - then the problem is not on client's (your) side.